# Windows Server MQ client interact with Unix MQ server

Tags: ibm-mq

I am doing lot of analysis for a new Java MQ client requirement got some doubts. Currently in the  Unix system Queues Queue manager all created where MQ server is running.

In order to run Java MQ client we are going to install MQ client on other Unix Solaris system. Mean while we had one windows server where MQ client installed before going to MQ client installation on unix System need to clear my clarifications.

Since I am new MQ.

Can we run Java MQ client from windows server to connect  MQ server unix system(Queues,Queuue Manager)

1. If yes what need for this to connect Windows Server to unix Solaris
2. The code is compiled with MQ libraries
3. Is any error will come to face.

It would be great if you provide steps or solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run the Java MQ client from any machine to connect to a queue manager on any other machine. The MQ Clients (Java, 'C' or .NET version) all support any platform to any platform combinations, and all support any MQ version to any MQ version. So for example, you can have a V8 Client on Windows connecting to a V9 Queue manager on Unix. Equally you can have a V9 Client on Windows connection to a V8 Queue manager on Unix, i.e. any to any version can be upwards or downwards.

In order to connect a client to a queue manager, you will need the client libraries on the client machine, in your case the Java client.

You will also need to ensure that your queue manager has a TCP/IP listener running and that you know the port number.

You will need a channel definition on the queue manager of a type called SVRCONN, and know the name of it. e.g.

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(MQGEM.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) DESCR('Channel for my client application to connect to')
```

In order for your Java client to connect to the queue manager it will need to use

- The channel name
- The host name of the machine where the queue manager is running
- The port number of the TCP/IP listener

If you face any errors, they may be related to connectivity, because your application is connected by the network to the queue manager. Remember to pay attention to any return codes you get from MQ, they will be in the form of 4 digits, e.g. 2059. For Java you should ensure you get hold of the linked exception. It may also be useful to look in the error log of the queue manager too.

You may also face security errors if this is your first use of IBM MQ. The queue manager is locked down by default so that remote applications cannot simply connect in and do damage (e.g. delete important messages from other applications!). There are a number of posts on here that describe these errors and their solutions. Best advise, get the MQRC code (4-digits) and the AMQERR01.LOG error message from the queue manager. Armed with this information you should be able to describe and diagnose any error situations you encounter.

Comment: Thanks you explained very well now my doubts cleared

Comment: @Maxtech, I would suggest that as you have stated the answer was explained very well that you accept the the answer, I noticed that you have asked 8 questions on this site and never accepted an answer, so maybe you are not sure how.  To the left of the question is a grey check mark, if you click this it will turn green and give both you and Morag reputation.  If you think very highly of the answer you can also click the "up arrow" to vote it up.

Comment: @Maxtech thank you for accepting this answer.  If you want to see all questions you have asked and accept other question's answers you can see a full list here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9720009/maxtech?tab=questions you may have enough rep to upvote now as well.

Comment: Hi In eclipse when I call _qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht); with additional parameter mqht it shows error looks like it required additional files and import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC also not supported currently I am using version 7.5 mq jar

Comment: @Maxtech that sounds like a new question.  Also note that as Morag pointed out you can connect from a newer MQ version to a older version, so you could for instance down load the Java-All client from v8, 9, or 9.1 and use it to connect to a v7.5 queue manager, the nice thing about the java-all client is there is just a single jar file to use if you are using the IBM MQ classes for Java, the file is called `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and contains all classes.  Prior to v8 (7.5 and lower) there was no such combined jar and you had to deal with many different jars.

Comment: Thanks for your answer really help .Thanks again for your quick answer

Comment: Some places to look for examples https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/mq-dev-essentials/ and and here is a good answer from Roger that has a sample java program: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563828/websphere-mq-issue-while-writing-a-message-to-queue-from-java-program/38594676#38594676

Comment: Thanks again I learned MQ little more today with you and Morag